# Boost Enable/Disabled with update Method in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

For bench-marking I want to toggle dynamically the boostmodule of Highcharts on or off. I thought I can change the `chart.options` for the boostmodule with the following:

```
var options = {boost: {enabled: true or false, useGPUTranslation: true or false}};
chart.update(options, true); // for updating and redraw
```

The values for true and false are set by selectBoxes in HTML. 
The problem is that the chart doesn't update the new options. It works with the animation-property but not with the boost-properties. Is this a bug/feature?

If I'am debugging, the options-properties are correct but only the chart won't update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:
The options-property was declared as a **const**. So the debug shown that the options-property has changed but it wasn't.